# BizTalk map outputs only 1 element of each. Why?

Tags: mapping, biztalk

Using BizTalk 2010.
I have XML data that is hierarchical in structure.

For example, it looks like this

```
Rec1
    Rec2
    Rec2
      Rec3
      Rec3
    Rec2
Rec1
    Rec2
```

I get this data by calling a webservice that returns it in one Schema. I map it to another schema and it works fine, I get the correct structure and number of lines.

But in a special case, I need to make a small modification to the data. I do this by mapping again this schema on itself, and mapping everything with a straight line left to right except the few fields that need to change.

When I do this, my output looks like this

```
Rec1
     Rec2
          Rec3
```

No matter how many records of each in my source, in the output it always outputs only 1 of each (looks like it takes the first one of each).

Any idea why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it was a combination of source data being slightly misformed and the schema not being restrictive enough (needed to define min/max occurs for the record types).
So if you have a similar problem you might want to check your source data file (in the Test Map feature) for correctness, and see if you can define your schema more tightly.